# Basic JSON-lib example

Tags: java, json-lib

I'm trying to use JSON-lib, but I can't get it to run without `NoClassDefFoundError`. Here's the code:

```
import net.sf.json.*;

public class hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String settings = "{\"hello\": \"world\"}";

        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)JSONSerializer.toJSON(settings);
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

And the command to compile:

```
javac -cp lib/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar hello.java
```

And the command to run:

```
java -cp .:lib/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar:lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar hello
```

I have also tried it with commons-lang3.3, which gives me different errors. I think it might be a version thing.

How do I compile and run a simple example with this library?

If there's a better library without crazy dependencies, I would love to hear about it. I've tried Douglas Crockford's JSON-Java, but I had similar problems.

I would need something with a liberal license, like Apache 2, MIT or similar.

Comment: You didn't actually mention which class is causing the error. That could be very important.

Comment: @RanReg - Yes, I am on linux, working without and IDE (unless you consider vim to be and IDE).

Comment: @laixer- Sorry about that. Each version had different classes throwing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you seek is right there in the POM file  https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/central-proxy/content/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.pom

You need the following dependencies:

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.0
commons-collections-3.2.1
commons-lang.2.5
commons-logging-1.1.1
ezmorph-1.0.6
```

optional

```
xom.1.1 (if serializing from/to XML)
oro-2.0.8 (if using the jdk13 version of the library)
```

The project's website (http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) also lists these requirements.

It's very likely that commons-lang-2.6 will work with json-lib 2.4 however I cannot guarantee the same for commons-lang-3.x.

Comment: Wow, now I feel dumb. I didn't expect a library this simple to require so many dependencies...

Comment: I guess "simple" is a matter of perspective. Have a look at the set of configuration options that JsonConfig exposes. Also, when the library was released it was the only one that allowed true 2-way serialization of multi-dimensional arrays; xml <-> json <-> java mappings as well.

Comment: I suppose so. I was only looking for a way to get/set JSON properties, which is why I was so surprised that I needed to pull in so many dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) instead:

- Apache license
- No other dependancies
- Simple usage

This is example:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

class Foo {
    private String hello;

    public String toString() {
        return "hello='" + hello + "'";
    }
}

public class hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "{\"hello\": \"world\"}";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Foo foo = gson.fromJson(text, Foo.class);

        System.out.println(foo.toString());
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(foo));
    }
}
```

And voila!

```
$ javac -cp lib/gson-2.0.jar hello.java
$ java -cp .:lib/gson-2.0.jar hello
hello='world'
{"hello":"world"}
$
```

Comment: I think this would work. I think the problem is that I need to find the correct version of the libs (as @aalmiray pointed out). I am creating these examples for a customer, so I'll probably end up using this in an example. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really need serialization. I just want to iterate, but thanks for the example!